# How to delete the sign in history of Messenger:Mac

Tags: macos, login, history, windows-live-messenger

How can I delete the accounts on the sign-in history on Messenger for Mac?

Is there any way to avoid the list getting populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sign out.
2. Press the “Sign in with a different account or change your online status” link.

   [image: Messenger for Mac]
3. Press the “Clear account history” button.

   [image: Clear account history]

Comment: Thank you for the screenshots, i already had figured it out, it turns out that my version was too old. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the history works for me too. Follow these simple steps:

1. Start Messenger (but do not sign in yet)
2. Under the "sign-in", there should be a link for "sign-in as a different user". Click this.
3. A window will pop-up with your sign-in credentials, click "Delete History" near the bottom.
4. Quit Messenger
5. Restart messenger (your username should not show up and you will need to enter your username and password since you have deleted the history cache.
6. Enter user name and password.